# GridGain No FileSystem for scheme: ggfs

Tags: hadoop, gridgain

everyone
I want to use GridGain in Hadoop 2.4.0

my hadoop config under that

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/hadoop-data</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
    <value>1440</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
    <value>131072</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>ggfs://ggfs@R</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/hadoop-data/journal</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>r,host002,host004</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.ggfs.impl</name>
    <value>org.gridgain.grid.ggfs.hadoop.v2.GridGgfsHadoopFileSystem</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy</name>
    <value>NEVER</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

finish setting and start hdfs

I use

hadoop fs -ls /

ls: No FileSystem for scheme: ggfs

How should I do

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the followings to the core-site.xml:

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.ggfs.impl</name>
    <value>org.gridgain.grid.ggfs.hadoop.v1.GridGgfsHadoopFileSystem</value>
  </property>
```

The second version of Hadoop File System API is used rarely. The most of parts of Hadoop ecosystem works through first version of API.

And if you want to use GGFS only you don't need to start HDFS services.